# Add image using loader and make image a button with event handler

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, loader

How would I make an image I load using AS3's loader class into a button with an event handler on it? Below is what I have started. And below that is my error I get when I click the message.

AS:

```
//call function that starts loading my image
callButtons();


function callButtons():void {       
        var spanish_url = root_path + "spanish.png";
        var spanish_loader = new Loader();
        spanish_loader.load (new URLRequest(spanish_url));

//on load complete call the spanishLoaded function

        spanish_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener (Event.COMPLETE, spanishLoaded);  
}


//add loaded image to my main_container set x,y and turn it into a button. 

    function spanishLoaded (e:Event):void {
        var my_spanish:Loader = Loader(e.target.loader);    
        my_spanish.x = 1062;
        my_spanish.y = 620;
        main_container.addChild(my_spanish);
        my_spanish.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, playSpanish);
    }

function playSpanish (){

        trace("IN SPANISH");
}
```

the error I am getting when I click the spanish.png on the stage is:  `ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on MyVideoPlayer_CS4_fla::MainTimeline/playSpanish(). Expected 0, got 1.`

I NEEDED TO ADDED evt:MouseEvent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `spanishLoaded` you add an event listener:

```
my_spanish.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, playSpanish);
```

`playSpanish` function will expect a mouse event:

You have:

```
function playSpanish ()
```

This should be:

```
function playSpanish (event:MouseEvent)
```